# Elastic net: Calculate 1 standard error of lambda (lambda.1se) via caret or by hand

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, glmnet, elastic-net

I try to tune alpha and `lambda.1se` (the largest value of lambda such that the error is within 1 standard error of the minimum) for an elastic net. In the `glmnet` package it is possible to tune `lambda.1se`, but it is not possible to tune alpha and lambda at the same time.

Such a tuning of both parameters is possible with the `caret`package. However, as a default `caret` only provides `lambda.min` (the value of lambda that gives the minimum mean cross-validated error). I need `lambda.1se`, but unfortunately I can not figure out how to calculate `lambda.1se` with the `caret`package.

**Question 1: Is there a way to tune `lambda.1se` via `caret` or any other package?**

If the answer to question 1 is *no*:

**Question 2: Is there a way to calculate `lambda.1se` by hand and tune it manually?**

Below, you can find some reproducible code, which illustrates the problem:

```
library("caret")
library("glmnet")

set.seed(1234)

# Some example data
N <- 1000
y <- rnorm(N, 5, 10)
x1 <- y + rnorm(N, 2, 10)
x2 <- y + rnorm(N, - 5, 20)
x3 <- y + rnorm(N, 10, 200)
x4 <- rnorm(N, 20, 50)
x5 <- rnorm(N, - 7, 200)
x6 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x1) / (exp(x1) + 1))
x7 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x2) / (exp(x2) + 1))
x8 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x3) / (exp(x3) + 1))
x9 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x4) / (exp(x4) + 1))
x10 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x5) / (exp(x5) + 1))

data <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)

# Tune parameteres with caret and glmnet

# Set up grid and cross validation method for train function
lambda_grid <- seq(0, 3, 0.1)
alpha_grid <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)

# Specify conditions for a tuning via caret
trnCtrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedCV",
                    number = 10,
                    repeats = 5)

# Create grid for the cross validation
srchGrid <- expand.grid(.alpha = alpha_grid, .lambda = lambda_grid)

# Cross validation
my_train <- train(y ~., data,
              method = "glmnet",
              tuneGrid = srchGrid,
              trControl = trnCtrl)

# Best tuning parameters
my_train$bestTune # Corresponds to lambda.min; lambda.1se is needed
```

One way to calculate `lambda.1se` could be to use the tuned alpha of `caret` within another cross validation based on `glmnet`. However, I am not sure if the derived value would be optimal.

```
# Cross validate with fixed alpha based on glmnet
cv <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(data[ , colnames(data) %in% "y" == FALSE]), 
            y = y, alpha = as.numeric(my_train$bestTune)[1], family = "gaussian")
cv$lambda.1se # Final value lambda.1se
```

Comment: What's the reason for not using glmnet?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ mark999. `glmnet` can not be used, since it does not provide a tuning of alpha and lambda at the same time. In `glmnet`, alpha is usually held fix and the tuning is just done for lambda. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I am actually facing the same problem here. I wish I could find a specific documentation explaining how `caret` performs cross validation to tune $\alpha$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: I think the question is also relevant when someone tries to use packages like grpreg which doesn't give you lambda.1se like in glmnet. But probably more suited for https://stackoverflow.com/